# XNA - Starting a platformer

Tags: xna

I have followed the MSDN Platformer tutorial and made a variant with it.

However, I want to make a Platformer like the Super Mario games. Although I prefer to make a game with a basic level, instead of a side scrolling level.

I've read certain documents about using Tile grid to create my levels. Are there also beginner/full tutorials available to create a start?

Basically need help with the first steps of setting up a level.

Greets

Comment: Can't you just disable the code that scrolls the screen?

Comment: @Lars: There are many steps required in making a game, even simple ones. Can you give us some idea of your current knowledge level with C# and XNA?

Comment: @Nic: My level with XNA is ndeed basic. I am currently capable to create a simple space shooter, meaning I have the textures + shooting.I will need a tutorial to help me get through the part where the projectiles actually destroy opponents though.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used XNA for about 6-7 months, but back when I was 'playing' with it, I was working on Windows Phone 7 games and learned a lot from this blog over [here](http://www.garethpw.co.uk/). His [tile engine](http://www.garethpw.co.uk/search/label/tile%20engine) worked pretty good for me.
Although it looks like it is for RPG-like games, take a closer look at the examples, there is a 2D platformer example there too.

You **must** read [this](http://blog.nickgravelyn.com/2010/03/know-when-to-be-lazy/), otherwise nothing will make sense :)

Comment: I'm not really fund of using someone else his engine. I'm rather starting from scratch and build my own level with making the unit collision also by myself.